# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] (trying to connect via (null))

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a Laravel application which I want to connect to a MySQL server. This is server is a MySQL server service from Azure (Azure Database for MySQL). The application is running within an `ubuntu:latest` docker container with all relevant stuff installed.

When I call `php artisan migrate` for that Laravel application, I get the error message:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]  (trying to connect via (null)) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = patchdb and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:759
    755▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    756▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    757▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    758▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 759▕             throw new QueryException(
    760▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    761▕             );
    762▕         }
    763▕     }

      +36 vendor frames
  37  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

So I checked the values in `.env` file and also called `env` within the docker container. The values look good. When I try to make a connection with `mysql -h <host> -u <user> -p` from my docker container, I can connect to that MySQL server.

I assume the problem is something with the secure connection. In Azure one can download a SSL CA certificate. In laravel there is an option `MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA`. I set the path of the option to the SSL CA certificate but the error still occurs.

**Edit**

When I simply call `php artisan db`, I am also connected to the database. This should be another indicator that the values itself are correct. But the call `php artisan migrate` shows me the error above.

Comment: `php artisan db` simply runs the MySQL command line client. It has nothing to do with Laravel connecting to the DB via PHP. Showing the database configuration contents would be a good first step to getting help.

Answer (score 4):

A little late for you perhaps, but I ran into this problem too and the root cause of `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] (trying to connect via (null))` for me was SSL/TLS trust verification failed.

That is, you have configured your application to verify SSL trust and the supplied CA-chain file is incomplete, or invalid, therefore the server certificate cannot be verified.

Comment: Found out that our CA file is configured in the wrong directory. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation with this same error. It occurred because the reference to the ssl certificate was using the relative path. I managed to solve it using the full path to the certificate.

Comment: This is likely the real reason! Use full path instead of relative path

Comment: Or at least, if you can't specify the full path (say you deploy on a cloud service that dont allow you to see full path) you can use relative path but remember to make it relative to the config/database.php file and not the .env file; eg you can put in the .env file 
../cert.pem if the cert is at the root of your project

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same thing - PHP Laravel connecting to MySQL on Azure using certificate file to secure connection and I was getting same error message:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] (trying to connect via (null))
```

My certificate CA-chain file was valid so there wasn't problem with incomplete or invalid file.

I needed to use different docker base image. Previously I used `php:8.2-alpine3.16` which had `npm` v8 and I was unable to fix mysql connection problem. Then I moved to `php:8.2-alpine3.18` with `npm` v9 and everything is fine now.

The main problem was about some incompatible MySQL PDO packages I think.